# How to set iOS Swift WKWebView native elements language

Tags: html, ios, swift, webview, wkwebview

I have a **WkWebView** base application, how can I set the language for certain native elements like the **months** in the **Datepicker** when using **HTML** `<input type="date"/>` and keyboard **Done** and **Cancel** buttons. These don't change with the preferred device language or the `<html lang="es">`

[image]

Answer (score 4):

add below item in `info.plist` file.

- keyname :
  Localized resources can be mixed
  (CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations)
- type :
  Boolean
- value :
  YES (1)

before image:

[image: before image]

after image:

[image: after image]

info.plist image:

[image: info.plist image]